# localized duration format for french

Tags: java, python, datetime, localization

What is the Python analog of [Time4J's code example](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/1d73d3ed38a546fe6e91c75a6720c288f54a842a/README.md):

```java
// duration in seconds normalized to hours, minutes and seconds
Duration<?> dur = Duration.of(337540, ClockUnit.SECONDS).with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD);

// custom duration format => hh:mm:ss
String s1 = Duration.Formatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss").format(dur);
System.out.println(s1); // output: 93:45:40

// localized duration format for french
String s2 = PrettyTime.of(Locale.FRANCE).print(dur, TextWidth.WIDE);
System.out.println(s2); // output: 93 heures, 45 minutes et 40 secondes
```

It is easy to get `93:45:40`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import timedelta

dur = timedelta(seconds=337540)
print(dur) # -> 3 days, 21:45:40
fields = {}
fields['hours'], seconds = divmod(dur // timedelta(seconds=1), 3600)
fields['minutes'], fields['seconds'] = divmod(seconds, 60)
print("%(hours)02d:%(minutes)02d:%(seconds)02d" % fields) # -> 93:45:40
```

but how do I emulate `PrettyTime.of(Locale.FRANCE).print(dur, TextWidth.WIDE)` Java code in Python (without hardcoding the units)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pendulum` module](https://pendulum.eustace.io/):

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> it = pendulum.interval(seconds=337540)
>>> it.in_words(locale='fr_FR')
'3 jours 21 heures 45 minutes 40 secondes'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`babel` module](http://babel.pocoo.org/) allows to get close to desired output:

```
from babel.dates import format_timedelta # $ pip install babel

print(", ".join(format_timedelta(timedelta(**{unit: fields[unit]}),
                                 granularity=unit.rstrip('s'),
                                 threshold=fields[unit] + 1,
                                 locale='fr')
                for unit in "hours minutes seconds".split()))
# -> 93 heures, 45 minutes, 40 secondes
```

It handles locale and plural forms automatically e.g., for `dur = timedelta(seconds=1)` it produces:

```
0 heure, 0 minute, 1 seconde
```

Perhaps a better solution would be to translate the format string manually using standard tools such as `gettext`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Python but babel-library states that it refers to the CLDR data and supports pluralization (French zero uses singular as you can see in your output example). It will be hard to model pluralization manually for all possible locales so I advise you to use babel if you consider more than just French. The only missing feature in your example is just the list pattern (comma versus "et") but you could - at the end - scan your output backwards and replace only the last comma by " et" (unfortunately only valid for French).

Comment: @MenoHochschild: (1) pluralization is handled fine during translation (the `gettext`-based manual solution). [There is a standard model (zero, one, few, many, other)](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules). (2) the issue with the `babel` solution is that it hardcodes the pattern that is probably ok for western locales but it might fail in a general case (`TextWidth.WIDE`) -- the manual translation allows to adjust the format as necessary.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly the problem with babel is that the unit pattern involves all units even if a leading duration item is zero (hours and minutes in your example for one second). To solve that issue it would be good if babel offers direct access to time delta pattern strings for further processing (Time4J uses this way - inclusive list patterns). On http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/api/dates/ I miss this option however. If you can live with French only then a manual workaround is probably better than using babel, sorry.

Comment: Or you open an issue to the babel team? Maybe they will listen to you. See https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/issues

Comment: @MenoHochschild: zero values could be easily handled using `if fields[unit]` in the genexpr. The issue is that I had to pass `granularity`, `threshold` parameters to get a more precise answer and it fixes the units (they are hours minutes seconds) and `", ".join` fixes the format. If I call just `format_timedelta(timedelta(seconds=337540), locale='fr')` then the result is `'4 jours'` and `'1 seconde'` for `timedelta(seconds=1)` correspondingly that is ok if I don't need a precise answer. I want to avoid the explicit format such as `"hh:mm:ss"` that might be inappropriate in some locale.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kotlin, I just came across a similar problem with the Kotlin `Duration` type with **localized formatting** and because I couldn't find a good solution, I **wrote one myself**. It is based on APIs provided starting in Android 9 (for localized units), but with a fallback to English units for lower Android versions so it can be used with lower targeting apps.

Here's how it looks like on the usage side (see Kotlin [Duration](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/) type to understand 1st line):

```kotlin
val duration = 5.days.plus(3.hours).plus(2.minutes).plus(214.milliseconds)

DurationFormat().format(duration) // "5day 3hour 2min"
DurationFormat(Locale.GERMANY).format(duration) // "5T 3Std. 2Min."
DurationFormat(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar").format(duration) // "٥يوم ٣ساعة ٢د"
DurationFormat().format(duration, smallestUnit = DurationFormat.Unit.HOUR) // "5day 3hour"
DurationFormat().format(15.minutes) // "15min"
DurationFormat().format(0.hours) // "0sec"
```

As you can see, you can specify a custom `locale` to the `DurationFormat` type. By default it uses `Locale.getDefault()`. Languages that have different symbols for number than romanic are also supported (via `NumberFormat`). Also, you can specify a custom `smallestUnit`, by default it is set to `SECOND`, so milliseconds will not be shown. Note that any unit with a value of `0` will be ignored and if the entire number is `0`, the smallest unit will be used with the value `0`.

This is the **full `DurationFormat` type**, feel free to copy (also available as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Jeehut/78534c27b24d78f14a3cbd3eebead861) incl. unit tests):

```kotlin
import android.icu.text.MeasureFormat
import android.icu.text.NumberFormat
import android.icu.util.MeasureUnit
import android.os.Build
import java.util.Locale
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.days
import kotlin.time.hours
import kotlin.time.milliseconds
import kotlin.time.minutes
import kotlin.time.seconds

@ExperimentalTime
data class DurationFormat(val locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()) {
    enum class Unit {
        DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLISECOND
    }

    fun format(duration: kotlin.time.Duration, smallestUnit: Unit = Unit.SECOND): String {
        var formattedStringComponents = mutableListOf<String>()
        var remainder = duration

        for (unit in Unit.values()) {
            val component = calculateComponent(unit, remainder)

            remainder = when (unit) {
                Unit.DAY -> remainder - component.days
                Unit.HOUR -> remainder - component.hours
                Unit.MINUTE -> remainder - component.minutes
                Unit.SECOND -> remainder - component.seconds
                Unit.MILLISECOND -> remainder - component.milliseconds
            }

            val unitDisplayName = unitDisplayName(unit)

            if (component > 0) {
                val formattedComponent = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).format(component)
                formattedStringComponents.add("$formattedComponent$unitDisplayName")
            }

            if (unit == smallestUnit) {
                val formattedZero = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).format(0)
                if (formattedStringComponents.isEmpty()) formattedStringComponents.add("$formattedZero$unitDisplayName")
                break
            }
        }

        return formattedStringComponents.joinToString(" ")
    }

    private fun calculateComponent(unit: Unit, remainder: Duration) = when (unit) {
        Unit.DAY -> remainder.inDays.toLong()
        Unit.HOUR -> remainder.inHours.toLong()
        Unit.MINUTE -> remainder.inMinutes.toLong()
        Unit.SECOND -> remainder.inSeconds.toLong()
        Unit.MILLISECOND -> remainder.inMilliseconds.toLong()
    }

    private fun unitDisplayName(unit: Unit) = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val measureFormat = MeasureFormat.getInstance(locale, MeasureFormat.FormatWidth.NARROW)
        when (unit) {
            DurationFormat.Unit.DAY -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.DAY)
            DurationFormat.Unit.HOUR -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.HOUR)
            DurationFormat.Unit.MINUTE -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.MINUTE)
            DurationFormat.Unit.SECOND -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.SECOND)
            DurationFormat.Unit.MILLISECOND -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.MILLISECOND)
        }
    } else {
        when (unit) {
            Unit.DAY -> "day"
            Unit.HOUR -> "hour"
            Unit.MINUTE -> "min"
            Unit.SECOND -> "sec"
            Unit.MILLISECOND -> "msec"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [humanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize) package may help. It has a french localization, or you can add your own. For python 2.7 and 3.3.

Comment: `humanize.naturaltime(dur)` in `fr_FR` locale produces `"il y a 3 jours"` that is not the desired output.

Comment: you should call `humanize.naturaldelta(dur)` to avoid the "il y a", though you still wont get a more detailed breakdown.